# how to delete all the rows of a csv that have the word "class" in the first column, except the first row that has it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('coords.csv',sep=',',header=1)
```

[image]

In this case, the header row that has the word "class" in its first column is repeated a few rows below, and what I need is to leave the csv file with only the first row that contains the word "class" in its first column and the rest remove them.
When I mean to remove them, I do not mean that they are left blank because that would affect the data, but simply remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little script to filter out those rows.  It doesn't load the whole file into memory, instead doing a read-write for every row, except rows that start with 'class':

```py
import csv

with open('coords_filtered.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_f:
    writer = csv.writer(out_f)

    with open('coords.csv', newline='') as in_f:
        reader = csv.reader(in_f)
        # Transfer header
        writer.writerow(next(reader))

        for row in reader:
            if row[0] == 'class':
                continue  # skip row / don't write

            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right you need to purge all the repeated headers appearing within data. If that's the case and the file is not that huge you can filter the dataframe after the read_csv using

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('coords.csv',sep=',',header=0)
df = df[df['class'] != 'class']
```

Edit: To make it working you must treat the first row, which has index 0 as an header so the dataframe can be filtered

Comment: The file is quite large, but what I need is to eliminate are the repetitions of the header row that are repeated for example in row 303, in row 696, etc ..., I already think that I omitted the header (I mean the first row) when I indicate header = 1, but I am getting this error when I put what you said `raise KeyError(key) from err
   KeyError: 'class'`

Comment: This give me a `sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,...,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.` and when I open the file it still does not delete those rows that they have in their first column `class`.